# How do i use generic type in my base class?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a class structure with a base abstract class with derived classes.

My base class looks like this:

```
public abstract class Graph
{
    public Dictionary<Vector3, int> Dictionary { private set; get; }
    public List<T> List { set; get; }

    public Graph()
    {
         Dictionary = new Dictionary<Vector3,int>();
    }
}
```

Then i have 2 derived classes:

```
public class Graph_Waypoints : Graph
{
    public Graph_Waypoints() : base ()
    {
         List = new List<Waypoint>();
    }
}
public class Graph_Tiles : Graph
{
    public Graph_Tiles() : base ()
    {
         List = new List<Tile>();
    }
}
```

But it seems i cannot do flexible types for my graph like this. The idea here is to create a graph that lets me use different objects for its nodes. Whether it be a way-point graph or a tile based graph.

But i am struggling to work out how to get the flexibility for it to allow me change the type when i create each new graph.

Am i going in the right direction here ? How can i get the type flexibility on my list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nearly there; you're just missing some key parts:

```
public abstract class Graph<T> // <-- Graph must be generic
{
    public Dictionary<Vector3, int> Dictionary { private set; get; }
    public List<T> List { set; get; }

    public Graph()
    {
        Dictionary = new Dictionary<Vector3, int>();
        // You could initialize the list as you did before, but it's cleaner to do it here
        List = new List<T>();
    }
}

public class Graph_Waypoints : Graph<Waypoint> // <-- Subclasses must provide the base class generic arguments
{
    public Graph_Waypoints() : base()
    {
    }
}
public class Graph_Tiles : Graph<Tile>
{
    public Graph_Tiles() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Also note, you do not need to explicitly write `: base()` when implementing argument-less constructors; the compiler does it for you

Comment: Ah thank you! Now i understand how it all connects together!